# TinyMCE license clarification

Tags: licensing, license

I am currently using the "text editor" (so to speak) [tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/tinymce/). And I'm building an open source project that I plan to upload to github once I finish it. My project is basically like wordpress (not literally a wordpress 2) but you can write notes, and other texts that require TinyMCE. And what I want is for my project to work even without internet, but I don't know how to do it since TinyMCE by default gives you an API that needs you to have internet to work. First I thought of copying the javascript that the TinyMCE API returns, but obviously before doing that I went to see the license to see how I can use the software. My program is going to be like a reminder or a calendar (I am not speaking literally) that is, it is going to be a private service for the user but that the user could install on his computer.

So it seems to me that the [self-hosted application license](https://www.tiny.cloud/legal/tiny-self-hosted-enterprise-agreement/) would apply. Although I have already read the license, I do not fully understand it. And in something so important I would like someone to tell me if I understood correctly, in section 2.3 I understand that I can make a copy if I need it but NOT in production, but then if a user doesn't have internet and that copy is needed, can i use it? I hope I have explained myself correctly.

Comment: You've linked to terms for "Enterprise Users" which I'm guessing is for people with paid support contracts. I found a reference to the MIT-licensed open-source code base at https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/ ("TinyMCE is open source and licensed under MIT") which links to a ZIP archive you can download, currently https://download.tiny.cloud/tinymce/community/tinymce_6.3.1.zip

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for clarification of a closed-source license. Such licenses are off-topic here.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I literally asked on stack exchange where I could ask this.  And they told me that this site was a good option. Where is the closed-source license?

Comment: @DFG, the license you linked to doesn't give you the rights normally associated with open source licenses. Therefore it is considered a closed source license.

Comment: @DFG You are welcome to ask about what your rights and obligations are for the version of TinyMCE code that is available under the open-source MIT license (i.e., the zip archive that I link to above). I don't know in what ways that code differs from the nonfree version, but it seems like what you want. The nonfree code/agreement has terms that fall far outside what free/open licenses allow, so we are not equipped to discuss what the nonfree license requires. We *are* prepared to discuss the MIT license on the MIT-licensed version of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above really provide all the answer that's needed, but in order that the question can be put to bed, I've presumed to summarise them.

The [self-hosted application licence](https://www.tiny.cloud/legal/tiny-self-hosted-enterprise-agreement/) gives you nearly none of the freedoms normally associated with free software, and so is both unsuitable for what you want, and off-topic for this site.

But the authors also do an [MIT-licensed version](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/#self-hosted), which you can download from that link.  That is suitable for what you want; you may copy it without restriction, and you may incorporate it into your code or just ship it alongside, provided you honour the very gentle obligations of the MIT licence, which can be read eg [here](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).